# Excel, how to prevent data from incrementing but also not copy formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, copy, increment

I am trying to drag the bottom right corner downwards to copy some data and it always increments my numbers that I want to copy. If I select copy cells in the auto fill options then it copies the numbers properly but also copies the formatting, but if I select fill without formatting it increments the numbers. I want both. My first cell has a strong border above it that I don't want every cell to have. However my data is in semi small increments of the same problem so copying the first cell once then dragging would be way to inefficient. Thanks for the help.

[Original data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Ff7.png)

[Using copy cells, right numbers wrong formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n26QK.png)

Comment: Using fill without formatting, right formatting wrong numbers

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLmkt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following formula in the any one of the columns you are not using and drag it down to the end of data. Then copy the result to your column E as values. If your helper column is N then:

=IF(E3<>"",E3,N2)

Comment: I said in my original post that this method would not work as my data is in many sets of around 3 cells that need to be the same but not copy the formatting of the first. Copying it that way would pretty much be doing the whole thing manually which I may have to do anyways.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include a sample data and expected result in the question.

Comment: I'm working on that right now, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Edited answer. Try that out.

Comment: It's fairly complicated but it works, Thanks. I wish excel had a built in way to do this and didn't require a formula.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in these situations is separate the values from the formatting.

1. make a copy of the column you want to edit (either adjacent to it,
   or outside the table you're editing).
2. On the new column - use copy cells in the autofill menu, or
   otherwise complete the values according to your needs.
3. paste the new column back on the original column **As values**.
4. Delete the new column